# Как получить дату в миллисекундах?

Tags: php

`strtotime($date)` выводит первое, нужно второе значение:

```
Epoch timestamp: 1461583095
Timestamp in milliseconds: 1461583095000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант №1

```
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );

echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); //Где u - миллисекунды...
```

Вариант №2

```
echo strtotime("21.05.1992") * 1000;
```

Comment: Это текущая дата, я так понимаю? А нужно из переменной

Comment: а откуда ваша $date знает про микросекунды? припишите 6 нулей просто :)

Comment: Уже догадался, спасибо!:)

Comment: Обновил) Добавил ещё вариант)

Comment: - Как умножить на миллион? - Припишите 6 нулей. - Пробовал, не получается :)

Comment: @splash58 три 000 нужно. так как вам необходимо передать в js он как рас на 000 отличаеться. Известная проблемма.